# Excel 'fill down' time suddenly increased dramatically (large spreadsheets)

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, large-files

I work with large spreadsheets (500mb+) in Microsoft Excel and sometimes fill down columns in tables of ~300,000 rows.

For some reason, seemingly after a computer restart in November, (I don't know if that would correlate with a Windows or Office update) the fill down time has increased a lot.  A fill down that used to take seconds now takes minutes and a fill down that used to take minutes now takes hours.

I have tried everything I can think of, repairing Office and testing a variety of different files and also reinstalling Windows but the problem persists.  There are no other apparent slow downs other than this fill down time.  Fill down time seems slightly less when I have fewer spreadsheets open but the difference is not significant and much different to before.

Does anyone have any idea why this might have happened and have any ideas on a solution?
Thanks very much

Comment: Voting to close as `Off-topic, due to inability to reproduce` by SO users.  in terms of helping with your issue, please state the Office/Excel version you have.  Additionally, if you're in Office 365 realm, verify that your settings enable multi-threading for calculations (can help with time).  I'm not positive we will get you an answer, but the more info to help the better!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,  yes it is Office 365.  Multi threaded calculation was already enabled in settings>advanced>general.  Excel only used 20% of my 6 core processor during fill down but I think that's normal?

Comment: are you using keyboard shortcut for doing " the fill down " ? If u do, (try to) just press Esc once ' fill down ' shortcut was pressed. Any change in performance?

Comment: Hi, I am not using a keyboard shortcut, I am just clicking the little dot in the bottom right hand of the cell.  BUT, I looked into what using a keyboard shortcut means, and so tried selecting the column for fill down followed by CTRL-D and the job seems to be being completed dramatically quicker.  That looks like it will really help, thanks.  by the way, pressing ESC during fill down by clicking the little square would have no effect, I'm not sure if that's a clue that something was not working as it should (I think ESC did stop fill down before I started to have the problem).  Thanks, Sam.